# The "Flag" action in mobile app returns strange text ("option_id")

Tags: bug, android-app, comment-flags, stack-overflow-app

When I flag a comment for example in the Stack Overflow app (version 1.0.4), I'm getting the text "option_id" as the result, as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

Is this normal, or it should be replaced with a meaningful message?